# Installing Homebrew fails with "The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported"

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, monterey, git

I am trying to install homebrew to my mac with

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

but, I keep getting this

```
amaku@Davids-MacBook-Pro ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R amaku:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: remote error: 
  The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

How can I fix this running macOS Monterey 12.3?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2899.

I ran `git config --global --edit` then I deleted everything (there were a lot of `instead of` declarations) and saved the file.

Then I did the homebrew installation and it has installed fine!